# 'System.StackOverflowException' when sorting a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

When I want to sort my GridView manually I get this error: gridview sort An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll

This is the line of code I run. "Melder" is the correct name of a column which I want to sort on.

```
gvOutlookMeldingen.Sort("Melder", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I use devexpress aspgridview to do that for me but i assume that's not an option...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['System.StackOverflowException' when sorting a GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946376/system-stackoverflowexception-when-sorting-a-gridview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Datatable in Viewstate when you bind first time

```
gridView1.DataBind();
ViewState["dtbl"] = YourDataTable
```

and then do like...

```
protected void ComponentGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = ViewState["dtbl"] as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

        ComponentGridView.DataSource = dataView;
        ComponentGridView.DataBind();
    }
}

private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

switch (sortDirection)
{
    case SortDirection.Ascending:
        newSortDirection = "ASC";
        break;

    case SortDirection.Descending:
        newSortDirection = "DESC";
        break;
}

return newSortDirection;
}
```

Take a look here also on MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Comment: All I had to do to get it working is change the name of the grid control to match my code. What a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to handle the PageIndexChanging and Sorting events"

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SortDataTable(GetYourDataSource(), true);
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
private string GridViewSortDirection
{
    get { return ViewState["SortDirection"] as string ?? "ASC"; }
    set { ViewState["SortDirection"] = value; }
}
private string GridViewSortExpression
{
    get { return ViewState["SortExpression"] as string ?? string.Empty; }
    set { ViewState["SortExpression"] = value; }
}
private string ToggleSortDirection()
{
    switch (GridViewSortDirection)
    {
        case "ASC":
            GridViewSortDirection = "DESC";
            break;
        case "DESC":
            GridViewSortDirection = "ASC";
            break;
   }
   return GridViewSortDirection;
}
protected DataView SortDataTable(DataTable dataTable, bool isPageIndexChanging)
{
    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        if (GridViewSortExpression != string.Empty)
        {
            if (isPageIndexChanging)
            {
                dataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}",  GridViewSortExpression,GridViewSortDirection);
            }
            else
            {
                dataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}",  GridViewSortExpression,ToggleSortDirection());
            }
       }
        return dataView;
    }
    else
    {
        return new DataView();
   }
}
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewSortExpression = e.SortExpression;
    int pageIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = SortDataTable(GetYourDataSource(), false);
    GridView1.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I need only to sort not paging. And I see that you want to access datasource. And I clearly say that I can't do this because I don't have a DataSource in my GridView

Comment: Sorry!I guess it's datasourceControl.And I don't use it.

Comment: @Tassisto Then how you display records in GridView?

Comment: I read data from Exchange Server and put it into a DataTable. I can't redo this action on and on just to sort this DataTable, because I will have to access it again from Exchange. This requires a lot of time to be done.

Comment: Like Bharath just said.I put it into a DataTable.Then fill DataTable to GridView1.DataSource.It's not a datasourceControl.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over your question here while I was having the same problem.

After doing some research and reading the MSDN help on the Sort method I would have wanted to ask if you were calling this method from within the GridView's Sorting event (which I did)?

This would be the wrong approach, because the Sort method calls the Sorting event again, which would result in an endless loop.

I don't know why, but Sort() is supposed to work only outside of the Sorting event.