# 'System.StackOverflowException' when sorting a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, stack-overflow

When I try to sort a GridView, the system returns this error-message:

> gridview sort An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll

This is the code and "Melder" is the name of the column to sort.

```
gvOutlookMeldingen.Sort("Melder", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: What type(s) of objects are stored in the "Melder" column?

Comment: the type of the objects is string

Comment: What is your datasource? Could you write your code of your sort method completely?

Comment: I don't have a datasource, the GridView is filled with items from Exchange Service.

Comment: do you mean you are looping and setting the contents ?

Comment: May I suggest you outline - in code - how you populate your gridview, and how you sort it? That way we may be able to better help you.

Comment: @j-steen i would have asked this, but that clearly modifies the question completely. that's why i told him to close this and open another question "How i sort stuff on GridView with Exchange Service as source", which seems to be the question now, and have nothing to do with this.

Comment: omg, check his profile.. he asked the very same question twice

Comment: I'm sorry ariel, you have to deal with it: you want me to accept your answers randomly. And I told everybody I'm new to stackoverflow and ASP.net

Comment: and I first asked another question, then I modified it. go back into history and you will see. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Datatable in Viewstate when you bind first time

```
gridView1.DataBind();
ViewState["dtbl"] = YourDataTable
```

and then do like...

```
protected void ComponentGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
DataTable dataTable = ViewState["dtbl"] as DataTable;

if (dataTable != null)
{
    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

    ComponentGridView.DataSource = dataView;
    ComponentGridView.DataBind();
 }
 }

private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
  string newSortDirection = String.Empty;
 switch (sortDirection)
 {
  case SortDirection.Ascending:
    newSortDirection = "ASC";
    break;

  case SortDirection.Descending:
    newSortDirection = "DESC";
    break;
 }

  return newSortDirection;
 }
```

Take a look here also on MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You are probably calling `Sort()` inside `gvOutlookMeldingen_Sorting`, which will call `gvOutlookMeldingen_Sorting` and `Sort()` again, thus generating a loop.

On the `Sorting` event you need to call functions that alter the data source and perform the query again. Or if it's automatically bound, you don't need to do anything.

*Resources*

- [Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) documentation